# trigger Approval Workflow Action using Power Apps button - Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, power-automate

I created a simple Approval Workflow in PowerAutomate. When that workflow is triggered Assigned to user gets an email with two workflow actions: Approve and Reject.  When I click on Approve workflow proceeds to the next step.

Then I created an Approve Button on Power Apps gallery. Now what I want to do is when I click on the Approve button, it will do the same what above Approve Button does. It should GO to the next step in the workflow.

Is that possible to achieve?

When New item is created following email is triggered.

[image]

When i approve, my workflow then proceeds to next step.

I want to make that event  happen with this button in powerapps?
[image]

Comment: What is the trigger condition for your workflow? Are you creating list items from Power Apps or from anywhere else? check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-simple-approval-app-using-powerapps-and-flow-in-sharepoint-onlin/) or [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint-scenario-approval-flow) article if it helps you.

Comment: Also, you can configure [approvals in power apps without using flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49O284deOAI). Or maybe try if you can fetch existing pending approval requests from Approvals in power apps using [Approvals connector](https://www.carlosag.net/PowerApps/Connectors/Approvals).

Comment: Ganesh i just uploaded few screen shots on what i am trying to do .

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid not. According to this [post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Is-it-possible-to-have-approve-and-reject-button-on-PowerApps/td-p/395343) and a relative [Power Apps Ideas post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/INTEGRATE-Flow-Approval-Buttons-Approve-Reject-inside-PowerApps/idc-p/344248#M27406), this feature is not yet supported in PowerApps.

Currently, we can only trigger a flow using PowerApps button and continue the flow outside the app.